# i am getting exception while sending sms

Tags: java, sms-gateway

```
package hu.ozekisms;

 import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class TestTcpSms {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


        String host = "localhost";
        int port = 33049;
        String username = "admin";
        String password = "abc123";

        /**
         * Connect to Ozeki NG SMS Gateway and logging in.
         */

        MyOzSmsClient osc = new MyOzSmsClient(host, port);
        osc.login(username, password);      
        System.out.println("SMS message:");

        /**
         * If logged in send "Text message" to number "+00112233"
         */

        if(osc.isLoggedIn()) {

            osc.sendMessage("phone number", "Test Message");

        }

        sc.nextLine();
        osc.logout();

        /**
         * Receiving message:
         * 
         * If you want to receive messages you can use doOnMessageReceived in MyOzSmsClient.java
         * That's an event, which runs automatically when a message is received. 
         */

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

```
package hu.ozekisms;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import hu.ozeki.*;

public class MyOzSmsClient extends OzSmsClient{

public MyOzSmsClient(String host, int port) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    super(host, port);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}   

@Override
public void doOnMessageAcceptedForDelivery(OzSMSMessage sms) {
    Date now = new Date();
    System.out.println(now.toString() + " Message accepted for delivery. ID: " + sms.messageId);
}

@Override
public void doOnMessageDeliveredToHandset(OzSMSMessage sms) {
    Date now = new Date();
    System.out.println(now.toString() + " Message delivered to handset. ID: " + sms.messageId);
}

@Override
public void doOnMessageDeliveredToNetwork(OzSMSMessage sms) {
    Date now = new Date();
    System.out.println(now.toString() + " Message delivered to network. ID: " + sms.messageId);
}

@Override
public void doOnMessageDeliveryError(OzSMSMessage sms) {
    Date now = new Date();
    System.out.println(now.toString() + " Message could not be delivered. ID: " + sms.messageId + " Error message: " + sms.errorMessage + "\r\n");
}

@Override
public void doOnMessageReceived(OzSMSMessage sms) {
    Date now = new Date();
    System.out.println(now.toString() + " Message received. Sender address: " + sms.sender + " Message text: " + sms.messageData  + " at: "+ sms.receivedDate);
}

@Override
public void doOnClientConnectionError(int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
    Date now = new Date();
    System.out.println(now.toString() + " Message code: " + errorCode + ", Message: " + errorMessage);
}
```

}

```
    java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in 
    your hostmachine    
    java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in 
    yourhost machine                                                                                    
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:25)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:233)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:206)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:236)
    at hu.ozeki.OzSmsClient.run(OzSmsClient.java:87)
```

can anyone fix this error?
I am sending sms through Ozeki NG SMS Gateway.

Comment: Code please! Also, please accept answers to some of your old questions.

Comment: How about showing us some code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't pay for the SMS gateway, that is why it doesnt work http://www.ozekisms.com/index.php?owpn=27

Am i right?

Another reason is that you maybe gave wrong sending parameters:

```
osc.sendMessage("phone number", "Test Message");
```

"phone number" should be replaced with some real phone number